# Good Project Directory Structure

Tags: file-management

What is a good directory structure to use for company projects? I have an svn repository that I want to keep clean but I'm not really happy with anything I have so far.

Here is what I have so far:

## Project Folder

1. Management

   1. reports

      1. quarterly reports
      2. final
   2. meetings
   3. schedules
   4. commercialization
2. Development

   1. software

      1. 3rdParty
      2. dev
      3. ...
      4. testing
   2. hardware
   3. documents

      1. documentation
      2. marketing
   4. references
   5. data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you work on multiple projects?  If so, I might suggest under Development to then have subdirectories for each project, plus a directory for common or library code.  Under that have the documents, the software, the database info, etc, like you have above.

Comment: Yes, multiple projects but each ones management and development will be distinct since the people working on it will have different meetings and timelines. I probably do need to work out something with common material.